# Fit all items in a div with horizontal scroll

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to fit all items with its original size into a fix width Container. I dont want to compromise the width of the children to fit into the container. I want to have the horizontal scroll in place.

I have tried flexbox to get them all inline but I am not sure how I can add the horizontal scrollbar in.

I want to show 5 blocks at a time with scrollbar.

This is what it looks like at the moment.

[image]

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Block = styled.div`
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
overflow-x: scroll;
`;

const Planner = () => (
    <Container>
        <Block>Block 1</Block>
        <Block>Block 2</Block>
        <Block>Block 3</Block>
        <Block>Block 4</Block>
        <Block>Block 5</Block>
        <Block>Block 6</Block>
        <Block>Block 7</Block>
        <Block>Block 8</Block>
        <Block>Block 9</Block>
        <Block>Block 10</Block>
        <Block>Block 11</Block>
    </Container>
);

export default Planner;
```

Comment: `overflow-x: auto` on the container should allow it to scroll horizontally if its contents are wider than the page (or its container, whichever is encountered first)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it just resize the children within the container to make it fit. No scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key aspect here is to remove the width of your items and instead set the `flex` property like so: `flex: 0 0 200px`. That will make sure that the items will neither grow, the first 0, nor shrink, the second 0, and have a width of 200px.

Then make sure that you container hides the overflowing content.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Block = styled.div`
  height: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
`;

const Planner = () => (
  <Container>
    <Block>Block 1</Block>
    <Block>Block 2</Block>
    <Block>Block 3</Block>
    <Block>Block 4</Block>
    <Block>Block 5</Block>
    <Block>Block 6</Block>
    <Block>Block 7</Block>
    <Block>Block 8</Block>
    <Block>Block 9</Block>
    <Block>Block 10</Block>
    <Block>Block 11</Block>
  </Container>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Planner />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Block component's css: `display: inline-block;` and remove flex from the container.

Comment: nope, doesnt make a difference. Still no scroll. Just squashed the children into the div.

Comment: Did you remove ```display: flex``` from the container?

Comment: It stacks them up.. i want them all to be in same line

Comment: Oh, right, I see why it's wrong. Then you could try having ```display: flex``` in the Container, and setting ```flex-shrink: 0``` in the Block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Block = styled.div`
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
`;

const Planner = () => (
    <Container>
        <Block>Block 1</Block>
        <Block>Block 2</Block>
        <Block>Block 3</Block>
        <Block>Block 4</Block>
        <Block>Block 5</Block>
        <Block>Block 6</Block>
        <Block>Block 7</Block>
        <Block>Block 8</Block>
        <Block>Block 9</Block>
        <Block>Block 10</Block>
        <Block>Block 11</Block>
    </Container>
);

export default Planner;
```